# how to generate data using MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to generate data using mapreduce with hadoop 1.2.1.
I don't want anything except java and hadoop.
( I mean that I will not use hadoop-ecosystem or etc. )

data should be like format ... (csv format)
Numbers,X-axis,Y-axis
1,1,2\n
2,3,2\n
3,12,1\n
4,531,2\n
5,23,4324\n
...

data size more than 1GB at least.

data is generated in parallel from no-input.

I have tried to run the source-code 
from [MapReduce Design Patterns 182p {Generating Data}]. 
But faild like these in windows Eclipse console and in linux.

(Ref => [http://www.amazon.com/MapReduce-Design-Patterns-Effective-Algorithms/dp/1449327176](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449327176) )

```
//////////////////////////////copy from my window+eclipse-console//////////////////////////
4월 22, 2014 9:35:58 오전 org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit>
경고: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Cant help it, hence ignoring IOException setting persmission for path "file:/D:/debug/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/BISTel_RWoo1622699850/.staging": Failed to set permissions of path: D:\debug\hadoop\tmp\mapred\staging\BISTel_RWoo1622699850\.staging to 0700
Cant help it, hence ignoring IOException setting persmission for path "file:/D:/debug/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/BISTel_RWoo1622699850/.staging/job_local1622699850_0001": Failed to set permissions of path: D:\debug\hadoop\tmp\mapred\staging\BISTel_RWoo1622699850\.staging\job_local1622699850_0001 to 0700
4월 22, 2014 9:35:58 오전 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2 run
정보: Cleaning up the staging area file:/D:/debug/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/BISTel_RWoo1622699850/.staging/job_local1622699850_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": CreateProcess error=2, ÁödµÈ ÆÄÀÏ; ã; ¼ö ¾ø
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.checkPermissionOfOther(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.isPublic(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.determineCacheVisibilities(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobClient.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobClient.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$400(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver.main(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:237)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, ÁödµÈ ÆÄÀÏ; ã; ¼ö ¾ø
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 24 more

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.checkPermissionOfOther(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.isPublic(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.determineCacheVisibilities(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobClient.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobClient.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$400(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver.main(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:237)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////copy from my local-linux-webpages: myserver:50030/jobtracker.jsp//////////
Hadoop map task list for job_201404151557_0017 on fox01

All Tasks

Task    Complete    Status  Start Time  Finish Time Errors  Counters
task_201404151557_0017_m_000000 0.00%

21-Apr-2014 16:17:00
21-Apr-2014 16:17:21 (20sec)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)


0
task_201404151557_0017_m_000001 0.00%

21-Apr-2014 16:17:00
21-Apr-2014 16:17:21 (20sec)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/rwoo/test/wordList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat$RandomStackoverflowRecordReader.initialize(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:116)
    at mrdp.ch7.RandomDataGenerationDriver$RandomStackOverflowInputFormat.createRecordReader(RandomDataGenerationDriver.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)


0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you have Cygwin installed. Or maybe cygwin/bin is not in path?

For Hadoop on windows+eclipse or just windows you need cygwin.

Comment: I don't use cygwin. Would you give me link or url about cygwin to install and setup  ?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop can be setup in windows using cygwin.
There are many documentation found in internet about it.
[Here](http://www.orzota.com/single-node-hadoop-setup-2/) is a good tutorial to setup cygwin in windows for Hadoop.